# Entity Framework Migration - Indicar migrações como executadas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migrations

Estou trabalhando em um sistema em ASP.NET MVC com Entity Framework, que usa Migrations.

Tem o seguinte inicializador:

```
public void InitializeDatabase(Contexto context)
{
     if (!context.Database.Exists())
     {
        context.Database.Create();

     }
     else
     {
        // se tiver migrações pendentes,irá executar essas
         var migrator = new DbMigrator(_configuration);
         if (migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
               migrator.Update();
    }
}
```

Está funcionamento corretamente no ambiente de produção já tendo sido executado algumas migrações com sucesso.

A migração inicial está vazia o que irá causar problema em outro cenário que vou falar abaixo.

```
public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

Se eu for publicar o sistema em outro servidor que não contenha o banco de dados, o inicializador irá criar o banco pois o mesmo não existe, até ai ok. Então no próximo acesso, ele tentará rodar as migrações, dando erro, pois já existem os objetos das migrações, pois foram criados pelo Database.Create

Eu tentei usar Add-Migration InitialCreate, mas cria uma migração em branco. Eu queria saber se tem alguma forma de depois de executar o comando Database.Create, teria como indicar que a última migração já foi executada.

**Edit**

Ao rodar o sistema quando  não há o banco, está dando erro no comando CreateDatabase

- entra no comando context.Database.Create()
- a migração inicial passa  pelo Up sem erros
- ao rodar a primeira migração MigrationErroUsuario11122015 dá o erro abaixo
- nem chega na verificação GetPendingMigrations()

> Additional information: Foreign key
>   'FK_dbo.ErroUsuario_dbo.Erro_ErroID' references invalid table
>   'dbo.Erro'.

Tenho impressão que tentou dar um create na tabela "ErroUsuario" mas a tabela "Erro" ainda não existia, ou não foi commitado o create da tabela "Erro"

```
    public partial class MigrationErroUsuario11122015 : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.ErroUsuario",
                c => new
                    {
                        ErroUsuarioID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        ErroID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        UsuarioID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ErroUsuarioID)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Erro", t => t.ErroID, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Usuario", t => t.UsuarioID, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.ErroID)
                .Index(t => t.UsuarioID);

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Então no próximo acesso, ele tentará rodar as migrações, dando erro, pois já existem os objetos das migrações, pois foram criados pelo `Database.Create`

Não exatamente. `GetPendingMigrations()` confere quais migrações ainda não foram aplicadas e as aplica. Migrações em branco, em teoria, não deveriam dar erro.

> Eu queria saber se tem alguma forma de depois de executar o comando `Database.Create`, teria como indicar que a última migração já foi executada.

Acho que um pequeno ajuste de lógica já resolve o problema:

```
 if (!context.Database.Exists())
 {
    context.Database.Create();
 }

 // se tiver migrações pendentes,irá executar essas
 var migrator = new DbMigrator(_configuration);
 if (migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
       migrator.Update();
```

> Tenho impressão que tentou dar um create na tabela "ErroUsuario" mas a tabela "Erro" ainda não existia, ou não foi commitado o create da tabela "Erro"

Acho que pra este caso já valeria a pena apagar todas as *Migrations* e gerá-las de novo em um banco vazio. Parece que a organização do seu banco está bem caótica.

Comment: vou adicionar alguns detalhes na questão. o erro está dando no CreateDatabase, nem chegou na parte da migrações do algoritmo alterado.

Comment: @Murilo Editei a resposta.